# KeyboardAvoidingView not working with overlay

Tags: react-native, overlay

I have a text input in an overlay in my react native application. I used keyboardavoidingview to make sure the keyboard doesn't cover my submit button but the entire overlay is not moving with the keyboard only the inside content is moving. Heres an image of what is happening. Is there any way to move the overlay with the content too?

[image: What actually is happenening]

This is my code

```
     <Overlay overlayStyle={{borderRadius:15,backgroundColor:'#f8f8f8',paddingTop:20,paddingLeft:20,height:300}} isVisible={showrevoverlay} onBackdropPress={()=>{resetoverlay()}}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView keyboardVerticalOffset={300} style={{flex:1,alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}} behavior="padding">
        <View style={{flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:'space-evenly',alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',textAlign:'left',width:'100%'}}>Review:</Text>
        <TextInput
            placeholder="Write review"
            style={{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}
            style={{ height: 200,width:300, borderColor: 'gray',backgroundColor:'#eef4f6',marginTop:10}}
            onChangeText={text => setreview(text)}
            value={review}
        />
        <TO onPress={()=>{saveReview()}} style={{marginTop:10,width:100,height:50,backgroundColor:'#4B53F2',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}><Text style={{fontFamily:'Montserrat-Bold',color:'white',fontSize:15}}>Submit</Text></TO>
        </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </Overlay>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to solve this problem. you can add your code.

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import {View , Dimensions,ScrollView} from 'react-native';

const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default class Overlay extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View  style={{flex:1}}>
                <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
                    <View style={{width:'100%', height:windowHeight }}>
                       /*Every thing inside this will shift up with out changing style */
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```